# JQuery selects first option when you create a select

Tags: jquery, html

If you create a page with a dropdown but don't select an option:

```
<select id="countries">
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>
```

`$("#countries").find(":selected")` doesn't return anything.

And yet:

`$("<select id='countries'><option>France</option><option>Germany</option></select>").find(":selected")`

returns:

`<option>France</option>`

Why?

**Update:**

There was no problem. On my page I had `<select size="5">` and thus nothing was selected. The JQuery counterpart does work as expected (it doesn't return anything):

`$("<select id='countries' size='5'><option>France</option><option>Germany</option></select>").find(":selected")`

Comment: add this : <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>

I think the first option is selected automaticly

Comment: What do you expect to get? Empty value?

Comment: Yes, the first doesn't return anything so I expected the second to work the same way. I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the html `selected` attribute to one of your items:

```
<select id="countries">
  <option selected>France</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>
```

Updating your jQuery code:

```
$("<select id='countries'><option selected>France</option><option>Germany</option></select>").find(":selected");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the error. On my page I had <select size='5'>

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/573/). $("#countries").find(":selected") is returning first option.

```
<select id="countries">
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>

$("#countries").find(":selected") //returns first option.
$( "#countries option:selected" ).text() /// gets selected option too
```

Answer (score 0):

I case you want to have nothing selected on page load just add and empty value to your `select`, like this:

```
<select id="countries">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qb5gj14h/)